# Proof that a group is finite

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$(G,.)$ is a group and $H$ a subgroup of it so that $G-H$ is finite. Prove that G is finite.

I found the next proof:

$f_a:H \to G-H ,f_a(x)=ax, a\in G-H$ . Since $f_a$ is injective and $G-H$ is finite it results that H is finite.
$G=H \cup(G-H)$   so $G$ is finite.

Can somebody explain me how it results that $H$ is finite, please?

Comment: Result is false if $H=G$--a group is a subgroup of itself.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The cosets of $H$ partition $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $H$ needs to be a *proper* subgroup of $G$ first of all.

Let $a$ be any element in $G - H$. Then $|aH| = |H|$ and $aH \subseteq G \setminus H$ [make sure you see why to both of these]. 
So if $G \setminus H$ is finite then so is $aH$ and (as $|aH| = |H|$) thus so is $H$.

Answer (score 0):

in general, if there is an injective fuction from A to a finite set, then A is also a finite set.